# Discord.js Welcome msg problem. How can I fix it?

Tags: javascript, discord.js, bots

I was trying to make my bot send embed msgs when the person joins. My code is:

```js
    client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
        const exampleEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setColor('#468dff')
            .setTitle(':wave:   Hello {user} and welcome to **{server}**.')
            .addField('Consider checking it!', member.nickname)
            .setImage(member.user.avatarURL)
    
        member.guild.channels.get('761871578178387989').send(exampleEmbed);
    })
```

But it sends an error when I test it with bot joining.

```js
    /home/runner/aftbot/index.js:23
        const exampleEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                             ^
    
    TypeError: Discord.RichEmbed is not a constructor
        at Client.<anonymous> (/home/runner/aftbot/index.js:23:26)
        at Client.emit (events.js:314:20)
        at Client.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
        at Object.module.exports [as GUILD_MEMBER_ADD] (/home/runner/aftbot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/GUILD_MEMBER_ADD.js:16:14)
        at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/home/runner/aftbot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
        at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/home/runner/aftbot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
        at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/home/runner/aftbot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
        at WebSocket.onMessage (/home/runner/aftbot/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:132:16)
        at WebSocket.emit (events.js:314:20)
        at WebSocket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix RichEmbed Discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62199891/how-to-fix-richembed-discord-js)

Answer (score 1):

Use `const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()`

As given in this link here -

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62199990/7895283

> Discord.RichEmbed got removed in v12.
>
> just use Discord.MessageEmbed instead.

Comment: Please flag the question as a duplicate if it already has an answer on Stack Overflow. Don't add it as an answer.

Comment: Hit the "Flag" button under the question, then select "a duplicate" and then you can directly paste the URL into the search box.

Comment: but now it sends, TypeError: member.guild.channels.get is not a function

Comment: Try this - https://www.codota.com/code/javascript/functions/discord.js/MessageEmbed/setAuthor